# Replace nested foreach for better performance

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I adjust this to give me a better performance, I have a total of 200 textboxes and 200 labels that I need to get their id and set their text values based on the id..

```
foreach (TabPage t in ASPxPageControl1.TabPages)
        {
            foreach (ASPxFormLayout formly in t.Controls)
            {
                foreach (LayoutGroup grp in formly.Items)
                {
                    foreach (LayoutItem itm in grp.Items)
                    {
                        foreach (var control in itm.Controls)
                        {

                            if (control is ASPxLabel)
                            {
                                string a = ((ASPxLabel)control).ID.Remove(((ASPxLabel)control).ID.Length - 4);
                                ((ASPxLabel)control).Text = fonction1(a);
                            }
                            else if (control is ASPxTextBox)
                            {
                                string b = ((ASPxTextBox)control).ID.Remove(((ASPxTextBox)control).ID.Length - 4);
                                ((ASPxTextBox)control).Text = fonction2(b);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you use a repeater?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt there is any performance-improvement possible with this solution as you´ll need to handle every item within your layout and cast it to `ASPxLabel` or `ASPxTextBox` accordingly - don´t you? So everything that you *can* do is some kind of syntactic sugar using Linq:

```
foreach(var c in ASPxPageControl1.TabPages
        .SelectMany(x => x.Controls)
        .SelectMany(x => x.Items)
        .SelectMany(x => x.Items)
        .SelectMany(x => x.Controls) { ... }
```

However this will produce more or less the same IL-code and thus performance isn´t improved.

Anyway I doubt your performance-issues - if even existing which I doubt from this code - come from this pice of code. You should definitly consider to use a profiling-tool such as DotTrace in order to find out what parts in your software run slowly - you´ll be supprised of the *actual big* points.

Answer (score 1):

You are unlikely to improve on the nested `for each`s since that is all Linq will do under the hood, where you can get an improvement is by not casting multiple times. E.g. change this:

```
if (control is ASPxLabel)
{
    string a = ((ASPxLabel)control).ID.Remove(((ASPxLabel)control).ID.Length - 4);
    ((ASPxLabel)control).Text = fonction1(a);
}
else if (control is ASPxTextBox)
{
    string b = ((ASPxTextBox)control).ID.Remove(((ASPxTextBox)control).ID.Length - 4);
    ((ASPxTextBox)control).Text = fonction2(b);
}
```

to this:

```
var label = control as ASPxLabel

if (label != null)
{
    string a = label.ID.Remove(label.ID.Length - 4);
    label.Text = fonction1(a);
    continue;
}

var textBox = control as ASPxTextBox

if (textBox != null)
{
    string b = textBox.ID.Remove(textBox.ID.Length - 4);
    textBox.Text = fonction2(b);
    continue;
}
```